# Convert Objective-C code to Java code

Tags: java, objective-c, if-statement

I need a little help with converting an Obj-C code to Java code.
Obj-C code :

```
NSArray * tmp = [_user.userDbAdapter executeQuery:query];
if ([[[tmp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"mediaType"] intValue] == M_COLLECTION_ANTHEM) 
{
    mtype = SECTYPE_AUDIO;
}
```

Java code :

```
ArrayList<Object> tmp = aUser.userDbAdapter.executeQuery(query);                
if(tmp.get(0)){
    //code                  
}
```

Is this the right way to do this...and how can I get objectForKey in Java ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will return an array of NSDictionary objects in the Obj-C code... in java my best guess would be it returns a array of objects that implement the Map interface (behaves the same way as the NSDictionary class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

You can then use tmp.get(0).get("mediaType") (if the objects in the array implement the Map interface that is).

```
List<Map>* tmp = aUser.userDbAdapter.executeQuery(query);  
if (tmp.get(0).get("mediaType").intValue() == M_COLLECTION_ANTHEM) 
{
    mtype = SECTYPE_AUDIO;
}
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't know that I can use get two times.Thanks really for the help!

Comment: There you go. Code edited and done for you. I think that should working (I am assuming the array returned contains objects implementing the Map interface though).

Comment: First get: List interface
Second get: Map interface

Comment: Actually If I use List<Map>, and after I change the type of query to List<Map> I can't use the both get methods. If i stick to the ArrayList<Object> type I still can't use the second get method....

Comment: That's because the objects in the List are not Maps... do this to figure out what they are: tmp.get(0).class.toString() <- print that to something where you can see it!